# Custom class does not work as HashMap key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

class A {
    int x;

    A() { x = 0; }
    A(int t) { x = t; }

    public int hashCode() { return x; }
    public boolean equals(A that) { return x == that.x; }
}

class Test {

    static HashMap<A, Integer> stuff;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stuff = new HashMap<A,Integer>();
        A a = new A(1);
        stuff.put(a, 100);
        System.out.println(stuff.get(a).toString());
        System.out.println(stuff.get(new A(1)).toString());
    }
}
```

Why does the second print statement give me a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You aren't overriding `equals()`. The proper signature is

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
                      ^^^^^^
```

Note that the type is `Object`, and not `A`. What you did was overload `equals()`.

Comment: Ugh, yes. Thank you so much. I will choose your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Always use the `@Override` annotation to avoid these situations; you would've been warned.

Comment: @user3217013 No problem! Just a tip; if you can configure your IDE to do so, make sure to (preferably automatically) put an `@Overrides` annotation on methods you think should override. Either you get an error that you aren't really overriding something (like in this case), or you'll get a warning that you're overriding something without the annotation (useful for accidental overrides)

Comment: @user3580294 Does the annotation serve any purpose besides warning me during compile time?

Comment: @user3217013 Nope, that's it. If memory serves the annotation only exists at compile time, and is removed when bytecode is generated.

Comment: @user3580294 Awesome! Thanks. Additionally, how would I access the member variable `x` of an `Object`?

Comment: @user3217013 You don't. Do an `instanceof` check, and if it returns `true`, cast to the desired type.

Comment: Or do a check of `if (o.getClass() == A.class)` and then cast. If you use `instanceof`, you might want to consider making the `equals` method `final` so that it can't be overridden in a subclass in a way that would be inconsistent with the reflexive part of the equals contract.